# Alsa doesn't detect soundcards anymore

Tags: debian, pulseaudio, alsa, alsamixer

Until today audio was working under Debian bullseye/sid, now it just doesn't anymore and I don't know why.

```
~ $ sudo alsactl init
alsactl: init:1759: No soundcards found...
~ $ lsmod | grep snd
~ $ # no other sound device
```

I've tried anything I've searched on the web, but just nothing worked. When I run `alsamixer` on the terminal I get this:
[image: alsamixer output]
Does anyone have an idea to fix this? Every help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated Linux kernel from 5.5 to the 5.6.0-1 and Alsa started working, maybe I've misconfigured something. If you're encountering my same issue, cross your fingers and try a fresh reinstall (modules, and other) of latest Linux kernel.